# How can I avoid having the sheetname included in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

The question is best illustrated with an example. Say I have:

```
Sheet1!A1=1;  Sheet2!A1=2
```

I want a formula in Sheet1!A2 to be 2-1=1. If I enter the formula as normal with mouse clicks I would have in Sheet1!A2:

```
=Sheet2!A1 - Sheet1!A1
```

How can I have Excel use A1 without a sheet reference:

```
=Sheet2!A1 - A1
```

A solution to this seemingly simplistic example would have a big impact on my work.

Comment: What do you mean by default to? `=Sheet2!A1-A1` works for me. Excel should only require the Sheet Name for cells referenced on other sheets.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear (I think). Looks like once you start using a reference on another sheet Excel make all of the following references include the sheet. @pnuts suggestion to rework the formula to have the local references first seems like the only option.

Comment: Maybe if you provide more context, there's some formula you can use so that you don't have to type the formula for each cell, and you'll instead type one formula and then click+drag to the bottom.

Comment: Unfortunately Excel defaults to using sheet names in formulas as soon as you have moved to a different sheet. The only way around it that I can see is manually deleting the sheet1! reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get

```
=Sheet2!A1-A1
```

By entering your formula in a different order

In Sheet1 cell B1 type

```
=-A1
```

Place your cursor between the "=" and "-" and select your cell on sheet 2

This bypasses the auto enter "Sheet1" because the code is already entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can also type in the second half of your formula instead of using the mouse.  From Sheet1!A2, type 
`=` 
then click on 'Sheet2!A1', then type '-A1', giving you 
`=Sheet2!A1-A1`